# How are the values in the Shapiro-Wilk table calculated?

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption

http://www.real-statistics.com/statistics-tables/shapiro-wilk-table/

I am trying to build a function that performs a Shapiro-Wilk test on a sample population, but I cannot figure out how the a-values in the Shapiro-Wilk weight table are calculated.

For example, if I have an array of 6 values:

```
array(2,4,7,9,10,12)
```

I know I would need to obtain the following 3 values from the Shapiro-Wilk table:

```
a1 - 0.6431
a2 - 0.2806
a3 - 0.0875
```

I have been Googling and researching for almost 2 hours and cannot figure it out. Could someone please help me?

Comment: The original paper is freely available at http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/articulo/shapiro1965.pdf.  It is linked from the first hit in a Google search for [scholar: shapiro wilk test](https://www.google.com/search?q=scholar%3A+shapiro+wilk+test).